# simple mantle JSON example from URL

Tags: ios, json

I have have some trouble in understanding what is needed to fetch a JSON file with mantle.h from a URL.

Can someone give me an example of how it works?

For example:
 -I have a URL www.example.com with a JSONFile as follows:

```
{
  "name": "michael"
}
```

How could I fetch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this process for fetching JSON:

```
NSURL *s = url;//Put your desird url here
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:s cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.00];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]init];
NSData *apiData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestURL returningResponse:&response error:&error];
dictionaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Now the `dictionaryData` contains your JSON. You can fetch it by:

```
NSString *name = [dictionaryData valueForKey:@"name"];
```

And make sure you are making async request. For this put the code within this block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    //Put the code here
});
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Call it with following method

```
  [super getRequestDataWithURL:urlString
              andRequestName:sometext];
```

You will get response in the following method if successful

```
- (void)successWithRequest:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation withRespose:(id)responseObject withRequestName:(NSString *)requestName {

NSString *response = operation.responseString;

id jsonObject = [response objectFromJSONString];


if(![super checkforServerRequestFailureErrorMessage:jsonObject]) {

        [self.leaderboardProxyDelegate leaderboardListSuccessful:jsonObject];

}
}
```

You will get dictionary in jsonObject